# Change resourcegroup when the 'from' resourcegroup-subscription is no longer active (ie disabled)

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I signed up for a Microsoft 'Developer Program Benefit' subscription for Azure, besides my normal paid account.

Now this account suddenly expired (at least suddenly for me, I now read that it only lasts a year).

My situation is that I have some storage accounts which are coupled to 2 resource groups which are attached to the 'Developer Program Benefit' subscription.

So what I thought I had to do was create 2 new resource groups attached to my paid subscription and then change the resource group for the storage accounts to these new resource groups.

So I am in the storage account
[image]

And choose 'change'

However, I get this message:

[image]

So now I'm kind of stuck. I don't want to re-create all my storage accounts, but I can't reassign them to the new resource groups either.

Comment: For this situation , you'd better open a new Azure support request from Azure portal >Help and Support.:-) .

Comment: Ok,thanks, will try that. Will see how support tickets get handled...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For visibility:

This is the documentation for specific cases based on subscription cases: **https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-subscription-become-disable**

**In your case** and to re-affirm Wayne's answer, you'd have to raise a billing **[support case](https://portal.azure.com/?#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Support/HelpAndSupportBlade)** and it will be handled for you.